# sfdx force:org:create error

Tags: salesforcedx, error, scratch-org

I was trying to create a scratch org using the below command

```
sfdx force:org:create -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a ScratchOrgHelp -d 30
```

and I am facing an error as below

```
ERROR running force:org:create:  The feature value FieldService requires a quantity.
```

I have used the same above to create scratch orgs before, unsure of why is this happening.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [specify the number of licenses you have](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm#so_fieldservice):

> ## `FieldService:<value>`
>
> Provides the Field Service license. Indicate a value between 1–25.
>
> Supported Quantities
>
> 1–25, Multiplier: 1
>
> More Information
>
> Available in Enterprise Edition. Enabled by default in Developer
> Edition. See  [Enable Field Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm#so_fieldservice) in Salesforce Help for more
> information.

This is likely a change in the Winter '21 release if it was previously working.